# How to assign a map layer to a button?

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I am trying to assign a maplayer GEOJSON to a button , whereas i have tried making it as a function but its not working well

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="geojson1" onclick="layer1()"> 
                                GeoJSON</button>

function layer1(){
 rainfall1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
   title: "layer1",
   source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
     url: './data/bsk.geojson',
    
     // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
     transition: 0,
   }),
```

Please help me how to assign this to a button.

Answer (score 1):

Your are only creating a layer, but you don't add it to the map.
You need to

```js
function layer1(){
 let rainfall1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
   title: "layer1",
   source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
     url: './data/bsk.geojson',
    
     // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
     transition: 0,
   });

  yourMAP.addLayer(rainfall1);
}
```

Comment: okay now how to assign this layer to a button?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12051309/sebastian How to assign this layer on a button

Comment: this function should add the layer to the map and when you add the function to your buttonevent clickon, everything should work fine. otherwise you should provide more code